# How to remove the margin from bootstrap navigation bar in hover?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

The Navigation Bar I got and edited is as follows and also the css code i tried to overwrite the bootstrap code is also included. I have included an current and expected output images below.

```
<div class="row fixed-top">
<div class="col-md-1"></div>
<div class="col-md-10 padding">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg  navbar-light bg-light">
        <span class="navbar-brand" >MySite</span>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMain" 
                aria-controls="navbarMain" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarMain">
            <div class="navbar-nav float-lg-right">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" ref="#services">Services</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#ourwork">Our Work</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#about">About Us</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link"href="#contact">ContactUs</a>
            </div>                   
        </div>
    </nav>
    </div>
<div class="col-md-1"></div>
</div>
```

The css Code I tried

```
 nav a:hover{
 background-color: green;
 text-decoration: none;
 margin: 0 0 0 0 !important;
 }

nav a:focus{
color: black;
}

.collapse{
margin: 0;
}
```

The current output
[image]

Expected output
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the expected output you just need to add 2 rules to `nav a:hover` as followed:

```html
margin-top: -8px;
padding-top: 16px;
```

Note that I've also removed both of your `<div class="col-md-1"></div>` elements and replaced them with one `offset-md-1` class because it's a bit cleaner that way.

Here's the full working snippet:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
nav a:hover{
    background-color: green;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top: -8px;
    padding-top: 16px;
}

nav a:focus{
    color: black;
}

.collapse{
    margin: 0;
}
</style>

<div class="row fixed-top">
    <div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1 padding">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg  navbar-light bg-light">
            <span class="navbar-brand" >MySite</span>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMain" 
                    aria-controls="navbarMain" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarMain">
                <div class="navbar-nav float-lg-right">
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" ref="#services">Services</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#ourwork">Our Work</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#about">About Us</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link"href="#contact">ContactUs</a>
                </div>                   
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read about margins, paddings and box model at https://www.sitepoint.com/set-css-margins-padding-cool-layout-tricks/

If I understood correctly, you want the green background-color to reach the top of the page without any shade of white in-between.

To answer your question, your CSS affects the links and not their parents elements (which control the space), and that's why it did not work.

You need to either:
1) cancel the padding-top property of `.navbar` directly

```
.navbar {
    padding-top: 0;
}
```

2) cancel the padding-top property of `.navbar` by adding negative margin-top to `#navbarMain`

```
#navbarMain {
    margin-top: -.5rem;
}
```

`-.5rem` might not be the case, but that's the default in Bootstrap 4 as far as I know.